# How to affect the nodes of the mesh with real values import from file.dat on threejs

Tags: javascript

I am working on a geometric visualization using Trois.js. My goal is to color the nodes of the mesh according to their values. For that, i have already created the nodes and i would first like to import the values from a file.dat, then assign the nodes with these values, in order to change the colors of the nodes according to their assigned values.
Here is the code.js I am using to create the nodes:

```
jsonURL = "/resources/datasets/Mesh.json";



var colors = ['#898ec1', '#9193bd', '#9999ba', '#a19eb7', '#a8a4b4', '#aea9b1', '#b5afae', '#bbb5ac', '#c1bbaa', '#c7c0a9', '#cdc6a8', '#d2cca8', '#d8d2a8', '#ded8a9', '#e3ddab', '#e8e3ae', '#ede9b2', '#f2efb9', '#f7f4c2', '#fcface', '#fff5d1', '#ffeac2', '#ffe0b3', '#fdd6a6', '#fbcc99', '#f7c38c', '#f3b980', '#efb075', '#eaa76a', '#e49e61', '#de9558', '#d88d4f', '#d18448', '#c97c41', '#c1753b', '#b86d37', '#b06733', '#a66030', '#9c5a2e', '#92542e']; 



$.getJSON(jsonURL , function setPoints(dataset) {
    var timestamp=1565715018;

    for (i=0; i<dataset.humidity.length;i++){
        if (dataset.humidity[i].time == timestamp){

           
            for (ii=0; i<dataset.humidity[i].data.length;ii++)
            {
                var dotPz = dataset.humidity[i].data[ii].x;
                var dotPx = dataset.humidity[i].data[ii].y;
                var dotPy = dataset.humidity[i].data[ii].z;
                
                var dotGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
                dotGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( dotPx, dotPy, dotPz));

    
                var dotMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { 
                    size: 0.0002,
                    color: "#ffffff",         
                    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
                    transparent: true,
                    depthTest: false,
                    sizeAttenuation: true,
                    
                } );

                


                scene.add(new THREE.Points(dotGeometry, dotMaterial));
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Does anyone know how to assign nodes with values imported from a file.dat? Any ideas would be very helpful!
Thank you